# Facebook photos.upload crash in Facebook Api

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, sdk

I need to upload photo on Facebook. But it seems to be impossible. I always have the same crash in console [UIImage dataUsingEncoding:]
The way I get my Image:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; 
if ([mediaType isEqualToString:@"public.image"]){        
    _photoImage1 = [[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] retain];
```

After all needed permissions:

```
-(void)uploadPhotoToFacebook {  
NSMutableDictionary *args = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
[args setObject:_photoImage1 forKey:@"image"];   
[args setObject:@"hello test picture" forKey:@"caption"];     
FBRequest *uploadPhotoRequest = [FBRequest requestWithDelegate:self];
[uploadPhotoRequest call:@"photos.upload" params:args];
```

It has crash after such a method in FBRequest.m

```
- (void)utfAppendBody:(NSMutableData*)body data:(NSString*)data {
[body appendData:[data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

}
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any crash messages in console?

Comment: Yes. There is a [UIImage dataUsingEncoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5a71800 I was tried to use NSData instead UIImage, however I have the another message [NSData datausingEncoding:]. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add image as dataParam

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
[params setObject:@"NAME" forKey:@"caption"];     
[[FBRequest requestWithDelegate:self] call:@"facebook.photos.upload" params:params dataParam:UIImagePNGRepresentation(_photoImage1)];
```

Answer (score 1):

thats't work right for me

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
[params setObject:@"NAME" forKey:@"caption"];     
[[FBRequest requestWithDelegate:self] call:@"facebook.photos.upload" params:params dataParam:UIImagePNGRepresentation(_photoImage1)];
```