# Post image on facebook wall using graph api iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook-graph-api

I have been trying to post a photo on facebook using facebook graph API. After authenticating user I am doing as following

```
        NSMutableDictionary *variables = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [variables setObject:@"some text" forKey:@"message"];
        [variables setObject:@"some link" forKey:@"link"];
        [variables setObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon@2x.png"] forKey:@"picture"];

        NSString *str = @"me/feed";
        NSLog(@"str: %@", str);
        FbGraphResponse *resp = [self.fbGraph doGraphPost:str withPostVars:variables];
        NSLog(@"resp: %@", resp.htmlResponse);
```

But my app crashes by throwing an exception:

```
    *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: -[UIImage dataUsingEncoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x11545140'
```

So some one can help me how do i post an image on Facebook wall along with some message using graph API.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3990433/facebook-photos-upload-crash-in-facebook-api

Comment: is this using graph APi? if so where can i find FBRequest?

Comment: yes it is .https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.1/class/FBRequest/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the given below code

```
NSMutableDictionary *variables = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:3];

//create a UIImage (you could use the picture album or camera too)
//UIImage *picture =selectimage.image;
UIImage *picture =[self scaleAndRotateImage:selectimage.image];

FbGraphFile *graph_file = [[FbGraphFile alloc] initWithImage:picture];

    [variables setObject:graph_file forKey:@"file"];

    [variables setObject:myPost.text forKey:@"message"];

    FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response = [fbGraph doGraphPost:@"me/photos" withPostVars:variables];
```

Comment: Thanks Aman. It was working fine for me. But why do we need scaleAndRotateImage. If i do so it is throwing an ARC error. Any way i remove that and added image directly. Thanks.